# How can we change appbar background color in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to set a common theme for app so I need to change `appbar` color as a color that indicates hex code `#0f0a1a`

```
const MaterialColor toolbarColor = const MaterialColor(
    0xFF151026, const <int, Color>{0: const Color(0xFF151026)});
```

I try this piece of code to make a custom color but fails.
How can I do this from `themeData`?

Comment: how it fails ? any errors ?

Comment: NoSuchMethodException shown in emulator. does primarycolor need materialColor?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Declare your Color:

```
const primaryColor = Color(0xFF151026);
```

In the `MaterialApp` level (will change the AppBar Color in the whole app ) change `primaryColor`

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
   primaryColor: primaryColor,
   ),
  home: MyApp(),
);
```

and if you want to change it on the Widget level modify the `backgroundColor`

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: primaryColor,
  ),
```

Comment: how can we define it for all the appbars in entire app with defining textcolor of appbar text?

Comment: Hello. This isn't working in Flutter 2.8 Can someone please confirm the same ?

Comment: True, it is no longer working in flutter 2.5+

Comment: This github issues reveals why this no longer works. Suggested workaround is to use colorScheme. (i.e. `theme: ThemeData(colorScheme: ColorScheme(..))`

But HugoH's answer below also works.

Answer (score 68):

If you don't want to change the whole `PrimaryColor` you can also define `AppBarTheme` in your `ThemeData`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
       appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
     color: const Color(0xFF151026),
  )),
  home: myApp(),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this should be accepted answer because by this approach we can leave our PrimaryColor as is, but at the same time specify color for AppBar not even created directly in our code (for example, showLicensePage)

Comment: This is the best way since it targets AppBar directly... the textTheme property should be addressed for styling the title... thanks!

Answer (score 23):

**In the current version of Flutter**, to comply with the new "Material You" design, we should try to use `ColorScheme` whenever possible. The app bar color is controlled by:

1. If theme `brightness` is `light`, use `primary` color.
2. If theme `brightness` is `dark`, use `surface` color.

For examples:

**Light Mode**

Set `brightness` to `light`, then set `primary` and `onPrimary` to yellow and black, and set all other colors to grey to showcase that they are not relevant to AppBar:

[image: light mode demo]

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primary: Colors.yellow,
      onPrimary: Colors.black,
      // Colors that are not relevant to AppBar in LIGHT mode:
      primaryVariant: Colors.grey,
      secondary: Colors.grey,
      secondaryVariant: Colors.grey,
      onSecondary: Colors.grey,
      background: Colors.grey,
      onBackground: Colors.grey,
      surface: Colors.grey,
      onSurface: Colors.grey,
      error: Colors.grey,
      onError: Colors.grey,
    ),
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Light Mode Demo")),
  ),
)
```

**Dark Mode**

Set `brightness` to `dark`, then set `surface` and `onSurface` to yellow and black, all others to grey to showcase that they are not relevant to AppBar.

[image]

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      surface: Colors.yellow,
      onSurface: Colors.black,
      // Colors that are not relevant to AppBar in DARK mode:
      primary: Colors.grey,
      onPrimary: Colors.grey,
      primaryVariant: Colors.grey,
      secondary: Colors.grey,
      secondaryVariant: Colors.grey,
      onSecondary: Colors.grey,
      background: Colors.grey,
      onBackground: Colors.grey,
      error: Colors.grey,
      onError: Colors.grey,
    ),
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Dark Mode Demo")),
  ),
)
```

Comment: how do I change the colors of floatingActionButton ?

Comment: It seems that for dark themes it now uses the `inversePrimary` color rather than `surface`.

Answer (score 10):

include backgroundColor: to appbar

```
   appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Example'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    ),
```

Comment: This is one is the solution in 2021

Answer (score 6):

With the new Material 3 and Flutter 3 updates, background color for AppBar can be changed using surfaceTintColor.

Either inside the AppBar like this:

```
return AppBar(
  ...
  surfaceTintColor: backgroundColor ?? CommonColors.lightColor,
 );
```

Or inside the ThemeData class like this:

```
ThemeData.light().copyWith(
  ...
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    backgroundColor: CommonColors.lightColor,
    surfaceTintColor: CommonColors.lightColor,
    actionsIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 4):

1. If you don't have a very special case -- don't change the app bar per screen, change it per app (for all screens).
2. Only use colors specified in your ColorScheme: background or surface:

   ```
    themeData = themeData.copyWith(
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        //  color: themeData.primaryColor,
        backgroundColor: themeData.colorScheme.background, //or surface
        foregroundColor: themeData.colorScheme.primary,
        elevation: 0,
      ));
   ```

Answer (score 3):

To change Appbar backgroundColor in the whole app:

```
MaterialApp(theme: ThemeData(appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey),),);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to `AppBar` description **On Flutter 2.5**, it uses  `ColorScheme.primary` by default.

> The default app bar [backgroundColor] is the overall theme's
> [ColorScheme.primary] if the overall theme's brightness is [Brightness.light]. Unfortunately this is the same as the default
> [ButtonStyle.foregroundColor] for [TextButton] for light themes.
> In this case a preferable text button foreground color is
> [ColorScheme.onPrimary], a color that contrasts nicely with
> [ColorScheme.primary].  to remedy the problem, override
> [TextButton.style]:

try using `colorScheme`

```dart
 MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
          primarySwatch: const Color(0xFF151026),
        ),
      ),
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
```

And to use somewhere else

```
 Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
```

Or you can just call `backgroundColor` on `Appbar`.

For more, visit [ThemeData-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using material 3. you have to take care of tint and forground color also.

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white //your color,
      surfaceTintColor: Colors.white // for material 3 you have to make it transparent,
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flutter ThemeData,if you want to set a theme for your entire application:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'MyApp',),
    );
  }
}....
```

Then if you want to change certain elements of your primary and secondary colors,you can achieve this using the colorScheme from Swatch.

[Learn More Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html#material.ThemeData.2)

Here is an example using colorScheme :

```
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyApp',
          theme: ThemeData(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,//the color of your Appbar will be blue
            ).copyWith(
              secondary: Colors.green,
//your accent color-floating action will appear green
            ),
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'MyApp',),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since flutter 2.5+, the working solution will be simply use `ColorScheme` in ThemeData:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: const AppBarWidget(),
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
          // change the appbar color
          primary: Colors.green[800],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('AppBar'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the background color, you can use [backgroundColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/backgroundColor.html) property, for the text color you can apply a style.

Example:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Jorgesys', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.cyanAccent),),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green, //App Bar background color.            
      ),
      body: Column(
      ...
      ...
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For Changing `Background color` of the `appbar` in flutter:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor:Colors.black,
      ),
),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).