# How can i make transparent appBar in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I want to make transparent appBar

So I looked for a way, but the examples put appBar on top of the image, but I want to put appBar on top of the widget, not on the image.

I want to know the way to make transparent appBar on top of the widget not image.

Here is my code

// main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(Main());
    
    class Main extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: SideBarLayout(),
          );
      }
    }
```

// SideBarLayout.dart

```
class SideBarLayout extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
                ....
          ],
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text('Help'),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                  bottom: Radius.circular(30),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Consumer<MenuItem>(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, MenuItem value, Widget child){
                  if(value.menuType == MenuType.pomodoro) { return Pomodoro(); }
                  else if (value.menuType == MenuType.calendar) { return MonthTable(); }
                  else if (value.menuType == MenuType.todoList) { return TodoList(); }
                  else if (value.menuType == MenuType.settings) { return SettingView(); }}),
                  SideBar(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Set `backgroundColor` and `shadowColor` to transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set the `backgroundColor` of your `AppBar` to `Colors.transparent` and `elevation` to zero as well as setting `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,` at your `Scaffold`.

```
Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    ...
  ),
  body: ...,
)
```

Comment: Good solution, but it doesn't get rid of the AppBar shadow. I'd also consider adding `shadowColor: Colors.transparent` to `AppBar` if that is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

The `AppBar` uses the primary color of the `Theme` object of your `MaterialApp`.

You can also change the `backgroundColor` property and set it to `Colors.transparent`.

Check the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740339/how-can-we-change-appbar-background-color-in-flutter#1)!