# primary color isn't changing the Appbar color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was following a YouTuber step by step creating this project but when I want to change the 'ThemeData primary colors' It just won't change and still remain the default color which is light blue. Here is a screenshot of it
[image]

Comment: You can find answers in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740339/how-can-we-change-appbar-background-color-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

According to `AppBar` description, it uses  `ColorScheme.primary` by default.

> The default app bar [backgroundColor] is the overall theme's
> [ColorScheme.primary] if the overall theme's brightness is [Brightness.light]. Unfortunately this is the same as the default
> [ButtonStyle.foregroundColor] for [TextButton] for light themes.
> In this case a preferable text button foreground color is
> [ColorScheme.onPrimary], a color that contrasts nicely with
> [ColorScheme.primary].  to remedy the problem, override
> [TextButton.style]:

try using `colorScheme`

```dart
 MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        ),
      ),
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
```

And to use somewhere else

```
 Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
```

For more, visit [ThemeData-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

The appBar while building first looks for the property *backgroundColor* in the AppBar().
If it doesn't find one it looks for the property *backgroundColor* in AppBarTheme() in the ThemeData property appBarTheme.
If it doesn't find that either, it looks for ThemeData's *primary* property.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        // appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
        //   backgroundColor: Colors.purple[900],
        // ),
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
          primary: const Colors.purple[900],
        ),
      ),
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
         appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
           backgroundColor: Colors.purple[900],
         ),
        ),
      ),
```

Or while building the appBar, just add the property backgroundColor to it, but that will only make changes to that specific appBar while the above code samples will make app-wide changes.

```
appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple[900],
        title: const Text('Your Title'),
      ),
```

Let me know if that works.