# How do I change color of app title bar in recents apps menu?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Please, look at the provided screenshot. How do I change the color of this bar? I don't know how to name it. Let's call it "color of app title bar".

[image: app screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we change appbar background color in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740339/how-can-we-change-appbar-background-color-in-flutter)

Comment: @JohnJoe, sadly, but no. I set the color of app bar to white and everything is ok with it, but the color of another app bar (that appears when you open the apps stack on your phone) stays unchanged. It still has default blue color from material design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! It's the "color" property of MaterialApp widget. Thank you all for your participation! :) Also, the name of this thing is "app bar in apps switcher" (or apps recents).

Here the result:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Аквамарин',
  theme: theme,
  color: Colors.white // this one
)
```

[image: change app switcher color]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change this color for whole application, you need to change ThemeData as follow:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    // changing theme color
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ).copyWith(
      secondary: Colors.green,
    ),
    // for changing text color and style
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText1: TextStyle(),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(),
    ).apply(
      bodyColor: Colors.orange, 
      displayColor: Colors.blue, 
    ),
  ),
)
```

but if you need to only change the `appBar` color on one single page, use this:

```
appBar: AppBar(
   backgroundColor: Colors.red //or whatever you want
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question points to another issue. The color of app bar is fine (I set it to white), but my problem is that I can't change the color of app in apps stack menu (where you can see the stack of all opened apps).

Comment: I think you should try changing your app's theme as I have suggested instead of just changing appbar background color.

Comment: @Samerset Are you asking to change the color of the bar in another app?  No, you can't do that.  You can only effect your app.

Comment: Thank you all, but I've found what I was looking for. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just add **backgroundColor** in AppBar :

```
AppBar( 
    backgroundColor: add color,
),
```